# How to translate OpenGL texture to CUDA texture?

Tags: opengl, cuda, textures

Here I have a OpenGL texture: GLuint tex1;

Now I want to use the tex1 as a searching table in CUDA, so maybe I should translate it to a CUDA texture.

As we know, CUDA texture, as a type of texture<>, comes from a CUDABindTextureToArray.

So, how to get a CUDA texture from the OpenGL texture?

Comment: See Section 3.2.11 "Graphics Interoperability" in the CUDA C Programming Guide. Also, you have asked a number of question about CUDA recently where it looked like you posted them, then abandoned them. Comments containing questions haven't been responded to, valid answers haven't been accepted, etc. If you have found your own solutions to those older questions, post your own answers to them and accept them. This shows the questions are solved and leaves information for others who might come along later. Stack Overflow isn't a one way street....

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should firstly register your texture with `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` function.

```
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;
cutilSafeCall(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&resource,text1,GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone));
```

Then you can get array reference to this resource.

```
cudaArray* array;

cudaGraphicsMapResources (1, &resource, 0);
cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray (&array, resource, 0, 0);
```

After that you can use your `array` and bind it to CUDA texture.